# Waiting for connectivity with ionic-v1

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-native

So, I had a problem after updating new CLI and instaling IONIC v-1 toolkit. But after install I got this problem

[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with ionic-v1...

its been 2 hour now and my app still not open

Comment: Provide your `ionic info` result here .

Comment: C:\projects\wooionic-master>ionic serve --l
> ionic-v1 serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8100 --livereload-port=35729 --dev-port=53703 --engine=browser
[v1] [23:47:43] Serving directory www
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with ionic-v1...
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with ionic-v1...
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with ionic-v1...
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with ionic-v1...
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with ionic-v1...
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with ionic-v1...

Answer (score 0):

I've just had that problem. I had installed node v7, so, I only had to install node v8. Restart the CMD and start a new ionic1 project. Try it!

Comment: Maybe you don't need to start a new project.